# How to define a wp-cron?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to make a wp-cron to `add_option()` hourly, but it doesn't work! (Actually it added to `_get_cron_array()`, but I think the function doesn't work.)

My WordPress plugin code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: A1
*/

function test_activation()
{
    add_action('test_cron', 'test_cron_func');
    wp_next_scheduled('test_cron');
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'test_cron');
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('test_cron')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'test_cron');
    }
}

function test_deactivation()
{
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled('test_cron');
    wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'test_cron');
}


function test_cron_func()
{
    add_option('Bookzisto1234', '1234');
}

register_activation_hook(FILE, 'test_activation');
register_deactivation_hook(FILE, 'test_deactivation');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your function hook and text_activation logic, try:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: A1
*/

function test_activation()
{
    if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'test_cron' )) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'test_cron' );
    }
}

add_action('test_cron', 'test_cron_func');
function test_cron_func()
{
    add_option('Bookzisto1234', '1234');
    // $log = get_option( 'Bookzisto1234' );
    // error_log($log);
}

function test_deactivation()
{
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled('test_cron');
    wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'test_cron');
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , 'test_activation');
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__ , 'test_deactivation');
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a true way,,,

Comment: This code works correctly on a clean installation, both the cron task is scheduled and the option added. What warning are you getting? Try un-commenting my debug log check for additional confirmation.